# How to use .dll 32bit run on Excel 64bit VSTO C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects in a solution :One is Console Project where communicate with PLC and another is Excel add-in project.

My Problem: using .dll (x32bit) and run on Excel 64bit. Control button by Ribbon button to connect or disconnect to PLC. So, I added Excel add-in project in Console Project's references  to use Excel add-in public class. But, i cannot call constructor of VSTO Addin

```
public ThisAddIn(global::Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.ApplicationFactory factory, global::System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : 
                base(factory, serviceProvider, "AddIn", "ThisAddIn") {
            Globals.Factory = factory;
        }
```

Here my code in Console:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using PLC2EXCEL_Addin;
using DATABUILDERAXLibLB;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace PLC2EXCEL
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DBCommManager dBCommManager = new DBCommManager();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            dBCommManager.PLC=DBPlcId.DBPLC_KV3000;
            dBCommManager.Peer = "USB";
            //Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactory _fatory ;
            //_fatory.GetRibbonFactory();

            //ThisAddIn thisAddIn = new ThisAddIn(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactory,IServerProvider); //i am not sure about this

            PLC2EXCEL_Ribbon pLC2EXCEL_Ribbon = new PLC2EXCEL_Ribbon();
            if (pLC2EXCEL_Ribbon != null)
                pLC2EXCEL_Ribbon.connectPLC_btn.Click += new RibbonControlEventHandler(startPLC2Excel);
            dBCommManager.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connect PLC OK");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public event EventHandler startPLC2Excel1;
        public static void startPLC2Excel(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //DATABUILDERAXLibLB.DBCommManager dBCommManager = new DBCommManager();
            //dBCommManager.PLC = DBPlcId.DBPLC_KV3000;
            //dBCommManager.Peer = "USB";
            dBCommManager.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Connect PLC OK");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And code in Ribbon of Excel Addin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;

namespace PLC2EXCEL_Addin
{
    public partial class PLC2EXCEL_Ribbon
    {
        private void PLC2EXCEL_Ribbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void connectPLC_btn_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)  //How to catch this event from Console project
        {

            //Catch event 
            MessageBox.Show("Connect to PLC");

        }
        public void abc() { }
    }
}
```

Sorry any inconvenience, this is my first post.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to use .dll 32bit on 64bit Excel,So I have solved my problem by create 2 separate projects:

- One is C# app adding .dll 32bit and communicate to PLC and send data 
  to opened excel  file.
- Anther is Excel Addin with ribbon buttons,
  launch/stop executive C# app when click  button